# how can i store keycloak offline access token in my local db?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm doing a spring boot application and I have also configured Keycloak authentication for my application. Next I want to store the offline access token in my db and use the access token from my db to check if it is a valid user when the user tries to use the application the very next time. Can anyone help me ? ..the keycloak documentation wasn't useful.

Comment: You do not need to implement this kind of logic yourself. Add Keycloak Adapter to Spring Boot and it will automatically validate incoming tokens for you. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter

Comment: @vadim  but i have a purpose for storing it . i dont want the user to go through keycloak login everytime i restart keycloak server . what i am trying to implement is ..once the user goes through keycloak login that token should be stored in db.and after that  the token stored in the db should be checked instead of going through the login part again even if i restart the sever....is it possible ?... can u help me ?

Comment: @TJ32: I'm also looking for the same thing. Did you find a way to store the keyclaok offline token in database? I have configured the mysql database and I can only see the offline session is getting stored, not the offline token.